Orientation of the Curve when deriving the Conserved charge in Conformal field theory
I am reading Polchinski Volume 1, and I am stuck at equation for the momentum operator in free scalar field theory in $2D$ euclidian space which is given as :
$$p^\mu=\frac{1}{2\pi\ i}\oint_C \left( dz\ j^\mu-d\overline{z}\ \tilde{j^\mu} \right)=\sqrt\frac{2}{\alpha'}\alpha^\mu_0=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha'}}\tilde{\alpha^\mu_0} \tag{2.7.3} $$
where $j^\mu$ and $\tilde{j^\mu}$ are the holomorphic and antiholomorphic current respectively.
$\alpha^\mu_0$ and $\tilde{\alpha^\mu_0}$ are the Laurent series expansion coefficients of $\partial X^\mu$ and $\bar{\partial} X^\mu$.
$$\\$$
Setting. $$\\$$
Consider a $2D$ euclidian spacetime with space coordinate $\sigma_1$ and time coordinate $\sigma_2$ where,
\begin{gather} -\infty\lt\sigma_2\lt\infty &&&
0\lt\sigma_1\lt2\pi  \end{gather}
Complexification of the space gives the coordinates $\omega$ and $\bar{\omega}\ $ where,
\begin{gather} \omega=\sigma_1+i\sigma_2 && \bar{\omega}=\sigma_2-i\sigma_2   \end{gather}
Doing a conformal transformation \begin{gather} z=e^{-i\omega} && \bar{z}=e^{i\bar{\omega}}  \end{gather}
converts the infinintesimal cylinder into a plane where the time flows radially. Our aim is to write down an equation for conserved charge $Q$ in $z$ frame.
$$\begin{gather}
Q=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}d\sigma_1\ j_2(\sigma_1,\sigma_2) \\ \ \\ j_2=\frac{1}{i}\left( j_\bar{\omega}-j_{\omega}\right)  \\ \ \\ \text{Since integration is along constant $\sigma_2$, Hence}\ d\sigma_1=d \omega=d\bar{\omega}.
\\ \ \\ \therefore Q=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\left( d\bar{\omega}\ \tilde{j}-d\omega\ j\right) \tag{1}
\\ \ \\
\text{In z frame,}\\ \ \\
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int d\omega=\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{cw}\frac{dz}{z}=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{ccw}\frac{dz}{z}\\ \ \\
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int d\bar{\omega}=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_{ccw}\frac{d\bar{z}}{\bar{z}} \\ \ \\
\text{cw is clockwise and ccw is counter clockwise}\\ \ \\
\end{gather}$$
When we go from $\omega$ frame to z frame the constant time slice in $\omega$ frame becomes a circle oriented clockwise because of the conformal transfromation $z=e^{-i\sigma_1}e^{\sigma_2}$ and when we go from $\bar{\omega}$ frame to $\bar{z}$ frame the constant time slice becomes a circle oriented counter clockwise since $\bar{z}=e^{i\sigma_1}e^{\sigma_2}$. Doing a conformal transfromation of j and substituting into (1) gives
$$Q=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{ccw}\left(dz\ j+d\bar{z}\tilde{j}\right) $$ which gives $p^\mu=0$ after evaluating this integral using residue theorem.
I think the mistake has to be in choosing the orientation of the curve. Any help appreciated.

First, recall that the Noether current corresponding to spacetime translations is given in (2.3.13). The integrating space for closed strings over $\sigma^1$ is $0$ to $2\pi$ in $z$ coordinates (which is just a circle in the $z$-plane). The conserved charge $p^\mu$ then corresponds to the spacetime translational invariance is $\propto \oint dz\: j^\mu$ (as Polchinski has already stated). Given $j^\mu_a = (i/\alpha')\partial_a X^\mu(z)$ and similar for $\tilde{j}^\mu_a$ (I am suppressing the $a$ index from here on out) then the momentum is
\begin{align}
p^\mu & = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint (dz\: j^\mu - d\overline{z}\:\tilde{j}^\mu) & (2.7.3)\\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\frac{i}{\alpha'}\oint (dz\:\partial X^\mu - d\overline{z}\:\overline{\partial}X^\mu) & (j^\mu = (i/\alpha')\partial X^\mu(z))\\
& = \frac{1}{\alpha'}\sqrt{\frac{\alpha'}{2}}(\alpha_0^\mu + \tilde{\alpha}^\mu_0) & (2.7.2\text{a}\:\:\text{and}\:\:2.7.1\text{b})\\
& = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha'}}\alpha_0^\mu = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha'}}\tilde{\alpha}^\mu_0.
\end{align}
So, the oritentation of the second contour was already given to you, the minus sign was because the contour switched to a counter-clockwise orientation due to it being an integral over the anti-holomorphic part. To make it more direct, just take equations (2.7.2a/b) at $m=0$ and plug-in.
For clarity, equation (2.7.2a) (and similar for (2.7.2b)) is
\begin{equation}
\alpha_m^\mu = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\alpha'}}\oint\frac{dz}{2\pi}z^m\partial X^\mu(z).
\end{equation}
Cheers.
